# Interaction of two orthogonal magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism

If two perpendicular magnetic fields(one in x-axis and one in y-axis) are interacting on a ferromagnetic material then if one of the magnetic field (x-axis)has magnetically saturated ferromagnetic material which decreases magnetic permeability of ferromagnetic material then will it also change magnetic permeability in other direction (y-axis)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to understand the quote that you wrote. Yes, it is true that for a magnetically staurated material in the $x$-direction will still affect the $y$-direction.
This is because when magnetic moments within a ferromagnetic material become aligned due to saturation in one direction, they collectively generate a magnetic field within the material. This internal magnetic field can modify the overall magnetic environment of the material, influencing how it responds to external magnetic fields, including those applied perpendicular to the direction of saturation. And the presence of of magnetic anisotropy further enhances this interaction.

Comment: Does it mean that if we would measure reluctance of magnetic material in x direction and y direction after saturation then will it show increased reluctance in both directions or it will show increased reluctance in the x direction (assuming the magnetic field in x direction saturated the ferromagnetic material)?

Comment: The reluctance will increase on the materials on both directions but with a more significant increase in the x-direction.

Comment: Is their any kind of data available or theory which will prove that reluctance will increase in both directions for a saturated core

Comment: Yes, there are theories and experimental data available that support the notion that reluctance will increase in both directions for a saturated core. The main theory is the theory of ferromagnetism and its interactions with magnetic fields and one  classic experimental technique used to study magnetic properties is the vibrating sample magnetometer (VSM), which measures the magnetization of a sample as a function of an applied magnetic field.With that data it has been possible to see how saturation in one direction affects the magnetic properties of the material in other directions.